# How to add third party plugin or code in wordpress like blogger

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I'am new to wordpress and i have used blogger it is good but presently i want to add the third party code to wordpress without using the theme editor. And iam using example.wordpress.com.

I mean like blogger by adding widget i mean like `html/javascript` widget we can add it but in wordpress iam confused to add it there is no third party widget in my wordpress dashboard how can i add the code. Help would be appreciable thanks in advance.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" data-value="grapes+">grapes</option>
  <option value="2" data-value="mango+">mango</option>

  </select>
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

$(".chosen-select").chosen();
$(".chosen-select").bind('chosen:hiding_dropdown', function(e, i) {
  searched_value = i.chosen.get_search_text();
  firstElementOnDropdown = i.chosen.search_results.find('li.active-result').first()
  if (firstElementOnDropdown.text().toLowerCase() == searched_value.toLowerCase()) {
    firstElementOnDropdown.trigger('mouseup');
    var t = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.chosen.input_blur();
    }, 150);
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dashboard -> Widgets -> Drag and place the text widget.
Paste in the code there. It would work fine. No need of adding additional plugin. It comes default

Answer (score 0):

Like blogger you can install plugin here. You can install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ and add your code.

Please install plugin from plugins->add new then upload your plugin zip and activate.

For more details you can follow this to intall wordpress plugin step by step
http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/